# Which SSD producer/line has lowest power usage?

Tags: ssd, power

What (current) 2.5" SSD drives proved to consume the least power in real-life measuring?

For "real life" I mean measuring the power they actually draw from the PSU, or the power the PSU draws from the grid compared to the very same machine with another drive. Measuring during stress and idle testing is fine, though an average of several hours real usage would also be interesting.

I'm not interested in values declared on paper, nor comparisons between different hard drive formats. If you want to focus on a specific size, let's say 250 GB which seems to be the most commonly bought one right now in Amazon.

Comment: This question seems easy enough to Google. Have you done research already that compares various manufacturers? If so, what did that research reveal (or not reveal) that you expect from this answer?

Comment: @Andy in my experience it's not so easy at all to find precise testing around the web; last time I searched, I did not find any. So, what I expect that I didn't find is the «For "real life" I mean» paragraph.